# How to get values from JSON start value like a?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonpath

I have a json like

```
[
{
    "text": "Acute Myelocytic Leukemia"
},
{
    "text": "Acute Myeloid Leukemia, Adult"
},

{
    "text": "Dengue Fever"
},
{
    "text": "Diphtheria"
},
{
    "text": "Familial Cold Autoinflammatory Syndrome"
},
{
    "text": "Familial Mediterranean Fever"
},

]
```

Now i want to take text only start with 'a' or 'b'.....'z'.

The Result like (Acute Myelocytic Leukemia,Acute Myeloid Leukemia, Adult)

How can i get this result in javascript or jquery.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A loop over the array, applying a comparison function is the first thing that comes to mind here (which is exactly what Array.filter does). What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

In plain Javascript? Try something like this:

```
function iterate() {
    var data = [
        {"text": "Acute Myelocytic Leukemia"},
        {"text": "Acute Myeloid Leukemia, Adult"},
        {"text": "Dengue Fever"},
        {"text": "Diphtheria" }, 
        {"text": "Familial Cold Autoinflammatory Syndrome" },
        {"text": "Familial Mediterranean Fever" }
    ];

    for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (data[i].text.indexOf('A') == 0) {
            // do whatever;
        }
    };
}
```

EDIT: Looking at the other answers - if you do have jquery embedded into your site, better option would be to listen to them and use $.grep. I always feel bad when other answers are better then mine, but hey - important thing is that we all learn and get better, right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/):

```
var matches = $.grep(data, function(item, idx) {
    return item.text.toLowerCase().indexOf('a') == 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If Jquery is an option [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkH7L/):

```
$.grep([
{
"text": "Acute Myelocytic Leukemia"
},
{
"text": "Acute Myeloid Leukemia, Adult"
},

{
"text": "Dengue Fever"
},
{
"text": "Diphtheria"
},
{
"text": "Familial Cold Autoinflammatory Syndrome"
},
{
"text": "Familial Mediterranean Fever"
}

],function(item){return item.text[0] == 'A'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (no jQuery needed). See http://jsfiddle.net/GycX6/1/

```
var matches = data.filter(function(obj){
    return obj.text.charAt(0).toLowerCase() == 'a';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check just the first letter with substr, then test with regexp?

```
var matchedResults = [];
for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var index = json[i].text;
    var reg = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    var first = index.substr(0, 1).toLowerCase();
    if (reg.test(first)) {
     matchedResults[i] = index;   
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X6u6k/1/

Answer (score 0):

it seems you want to get all the elements which starts with a letter (a-z,A-Z)

assume you assinged your object to the variable name 'koko'.
try the following:

```
    for(var i=0;i < koko.length; i++) { 
        if (koko[i].text.match(/^[a-zA-Z]/)) 
            {
              console.log(koko[i].text);
           }
 }
```

match(/^[a-zA-Z]/) uses regular expressions to take only elements with property text starting with a letter.

Comment: @G Z : I understand your confusion but he meant to look for values that only start with an certain letter (like "A"), not any letter.

Comment: ahhh in that case my code is not good for him.

Comment: I thought the same as you did, when I first read the question. Then I looked at his example output (with only texts that start with an "A")